# How does the Construct Rectangle algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I'm working on a brain-teaser problem, and I have the correct solution, but would like clarification on how it works. More specifically why is the square root of the area needed here, and what value does the solution decrementing every time until the area modulo w == 0? Is there a geometry principle using the square root of the area?

Solution:

```
public int[] constructRectangle(int area) {
    int w = (int)Math.sqrt(area);
    while (area%w!=0) w--;
    return new int[]{area/w, w};
}
```

Problem:

Construct the Rectangle Add to List

For a web developer, it is very important to know how to design a web page's size. So, given a specific rectangular web page’s area, your job by now is to design a rectangular web page, whose length L and width W satisfy the following requirements:

1. The area of the rectangular web page you designed must equal to the given target area.
2. The width W should not be larger than the length L, which means L >= W.
3. The difference between length L and width W should be as small as possible.

You need to output the length L and the width W of the web page you designed in sequence.

Example:

Input: 4

Output: [2, 2]

Explanation: The target area is 4, and all the possible ways to construct it are [1,4], [2,2], [4,1]. 
But according to requirement 2, [1,4] is illegal; according to requirement 3,  [4,1] is not optimal compared to [2,2]. So the length L is 2, and the width W is 2.

Comment: The area of a rectangle may not always be a perfect square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int w = (int)Math.sqrt(area);
```

Find the integer `w` closest to the sqrt of `area`

```
while (area%w!=0) w--;
```

Decrement `w` until it divides into `area` with no remainder.

```
return new int[]{area/w, w};
```

If `w` divides into `area` with no remainder, then the height must be `area/w`.

Starting from the square root of `area` means your rectangle will have height and width as close as possible.

Of course if your area is a prime number than you'll end up with `w = 1 h = area`.